# Slack with WebRTCPipeWireCapture Wyaland Black screen sharing but works on chrome

Tags: wayland, slack, 23.10

I am using

- Ubuntu 23.10
- Slack 4.35.121
- Pipewire 0.3.79-2
- amdgpu

```
➜  ~ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE                        
wayland

➜  ~ sudo lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6650 XT / 6700S / 6800S] (rev c0)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6650 XT]
        Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
        Kernel modules: amdgpu
--
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt [Radeon 680M] (rev c7)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Rembrandt [Radeon 680M]
        Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
        Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

pipewire

```
➜  ~ dpkg -l | grep -i pipewire                                 
ii  gnome-remote-desktop                             45.0-1                                    amd64        Remote desktop daemon for GNOME using PipeWire
ii  gstreamer1.0-pipewire:amd64                      0.3.79-2                                  amd64        GStreamer 1.0 plugin for the PipeWire multimedia server
ii  libpipewire-0.3-0:amd64                          0.3.79-2                                  amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server
ii  libpipewire-0.3-common                           0.3.79-2                                  all          libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - common files
ii  libpipewire-0.3-modules:amd64                    0.3.79-2                                  amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - modules
ii  libspa-0.2-bluetooth:amd64                       0.3.79-2                                  amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - bluetooth plugins
ii  libspa-0.2-modules:amd64                         0.3.79-2                                  amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server Simple Plugin API - modules
ii  pipewire:amd64                                   0.3.79-2                                  amd64        audio and video processing engine multimedia server
ii  pipewire-alsa:amd64                              0.3.79-2                                  amd64        PipeWire ALSA plugin
ii  pipewire-audio                                   0.3.79-2                                  all          recommended set of PipeWire packages for a standard audio desktop use
ii  pipewire-bin                                     0.3.79-2                                  amd64        PipeWire multimedia server - programs
ii  pipewire-pulse                                   0.3.79-2                                  amd64        PipeWire PulseAudio daemon
ii  wireplumber
```

1. snap version of slack with (or without) `slack --enable-features=WebRTCPipeWireCapturer` shows black screen when sharing
2. Screen Sharing works on Xorg
3. Screen Sharing works on chromium based browser (Brave)
4. Deb version of slack slack-desktop-4.34.121-amd64 - Black screen when sharing
5. Previously I had Fedora 37 on 6.12 kernel gnome 43 and slack was able to share screen so it's definitely possible

I got following in the logs I see that there are some subprocesses with flag of disabled WebRTCPipeWireCapturer

```
user+   26075  7.3  0.5 1178928616 180012 ?   SLl  11:27   0:02 /snap/slack/110/usr/lib/slack/slack --no-sandbox --enable-features=WebRTCPipeWireCapturer --executed-from=/home/user --pid=25496
user+   26082  0.0  0.1 33988524 49408 ?      S    11:27   0:00 /snap/slack/110/usr/lib/slack/slack --type=zygote --no-zygote-sandbox --no-sandbox
user+   26083  0.0  0.1 33988520 49280 ?      S    11:27   0:00 /snap/slack/110/usr/lib/slack/slack --type=zygote --no-sandbox
user+   26099  0.0  0.0 33588712 3200 ?       Sl   11:27   0:00 /snap/slack/110/usr/lib/slack/chrome_crashpad_handler --monitor-self-annotation=ptype=crashpad-handler --no-upload-gzip --database=/home/user/snap/slack/110/.config/Slack/Crashpad --url=https://slack.com/apps/sentryproxy/api/5277886/minidump/?sentry_key=fd30fe469dbf4aec9db40548e5acf91e --annotation=_productName=Slack --annotation=_version=4.35.121 --annotation=lsb-release=Ubuntu Core 18 --annotation=plat=Linux --annotation=prod=Electron --annotation=sentry___initialScope={"release":"Slack@4.35.121","environment":"production","user":{"id":"e1f78694-1d56-4017-a027-beab0ea663ae"},"tags":{"uuid":"e1f78694-1d56-4017-a027-beab0ea663ae"}} --annotation=ver=27.0.0 --initial-client-fd=43 --shared-client-connection
user+   26126  2.2  0.2 34046980 72972 ?      Sl   11:27   0:00 /snap/slack/110/usr/lib/slack/slack --type=utility --utility-sub-type=network.mojom.NetworkService --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=none --no-sandbox --enable-logging --crashpad-handler-pid=26099 --enable-crash-reporter=f0b3e071-ce2a-4a61-89db-a168791729e9,no_channel --user-data-dir=/home/user/snap/slack/110/.config/Slack --standard-schemes=app,slack-webapp-dev --secure-schemes=app,slack-webapp-dev --bypasscsp-schemes=slack-webapp-dev --cors-schemes=slack-webapp-dev --fetch-schemes=slack-webapp-dev --service-worker-schemes=slack-webapp-dev --streaming-schemes --enable-logging --log-file=/home/user/snap/slack/110/.config/Slack/logs/default/electron_debug.log --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,8702521800839048508,11262088157928811340,262144 --disable-features=AllowAggressiveThrottlingWithWebSocket,CalculateNativeWinOcclusion,HardwareMediaKeyHandling,IntensiveWakeUpThrottling,LogJsConsoleMessages,RequestInitiatorSiteLockEnfocement,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess,WebRTCPipeWireCapturer,WebRtcHideLocalIpsWithMdns,WinRetrieveSuggestionsOnlyOnDemand
user+   26179 37.9  1.3 1191407300 418572 ?   Sl   11:27   0:11 /snap/slack/110/usr/lib/slack/slack --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=26099 --enable-crash-reporter=f0b3e071-ce2a-4a61-89db-a168791729e9,no_channel --user-data-dir=/home/user/snap/slack/110/.config/Slack --standard-schemes=app,slack-webapp-dev --secure-schemes=app,slack-webapp-dev --bypasscsp-schemes=slack-webapp-dev --cors-schemes=slack-webapp-dev --fetch-schemes=slack-webapp-dev --service-worker-schemes=slack-webapp-dev --streaming-schemes --app-path=/snap/slack/110/usr/lib/slack/resources/app.asar --enable-sandbox --enable-blink-features=ExperimentalJSProfiler --disable-blink-features --first-renderer-process --no-sandbox --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --enable-logging --force-color-profile=srgb --log-file=/home/user/snap/slack/110/.config/Slack/logs/default/electron_debug.log --lang=en-US --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=4 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1698307092377958 --launch-time-ticks=5365682318 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,8702521800839048508,11262088157928811340,262144 --disable-features=AllowAggressiveThrottlingWithWebSocket,CalculateNativeWinOcclusion,HardwareMediaKeyHandling,IntensiveWakeUpThrottling,LogJsConsoleMessages,RequestInitiatorSiteLockEnfocement,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess,WebRTCPipeWireCapturer,WebRtcHideLocalIpsWithMdns,WinRetrieveSuggestionsOnlyOnDemand --window-type=main
user+   26229  7.5  0.3 34636732 127500 ?     Sl   11:27   0:02 /snap/slack/110/usr/lib/slack/slack --type=gpu-process --no-sandbox --enable-logging --crashpad-handler-pid=26099 --enable-crash-reporter=f0b3e071-ce2a-4a61-89db-a168791729e9,no_channel --user-data-dir=/home/user/snap/slack/110/.config/Slack --gpu-preferences=WAAAAAAAAAAgAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgAAAAAAA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAGAAAAAAAAAAYAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAA== --use-gl=angle --use-angle=swiftshader-webgl --enable-logging --log-file=/home/user/snap/slack/110/.config/Slack/logs/default/electron_debug.log --shared-files --field-trial-handle=0,i,8702521800839048508,11262088157928811340,262144 --disable-features=AllowAggressiveThrottlingWithWebSocket,CalculateNativeWinOcclusion,HardwareMediaKeyHandling,IntensiveWakeUpThrottling,LogJsConsoleMessages,RequestInitiatorSiteLockEnfocement,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess,WebRTCPipeWireCapturer,WebRtcHideLocalIpsWithMdns,WinRetrieveSuggestionsOnlyOnDemand
user+   26318  5.7  0.2 34227536 64128 ?      Sl   11:27   0:01 /snap/slack/110/usr/lib/slack/slack --type=utility --utility-sub-type=audio.mojom.AudioService --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=none --no-sandbox --enable-logging --crashpad-handler-pid=26099 --enable-crash-reporter=f0b3e071-ce2a-4a61-89db-a168791729e9,no_channel --user-data-dir=/home/user/snap/slack/110/.config/Slack --standard-schemes=app,slack-webapp-dev --secure-schemes=app,slack-webapp-dev --bypasscsp-schemes=slack-webapp-dev --cors-schemes=slack-webapp-dev --fetch-schemes=slack-webapp-dev --service-worker-schemes=slack-webapp-dev --streaming-schemes --enable-logging --log-file=/home/user/snap/slack/110/.config/Slack/logs/default/electron_debug.log --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,8702521800839048508,11262088157928811340,262144 --disable-features=AllowAggressiveThrottlingWithWebSocket,CalculateNativeWinOcclusion,HardwareMediaKeyHandling,IntensiveWakeUpThrottling,LogJsConsoleMessages,RequestInitiatorSiteLockEnfocement,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess,WebRTCPipeWireCapturer,WebRtcHideLocalIpsWithMdns,WinRetrieveSuggestionsOnlyOnDemand
user+   26366  0.0  0.0  17784  2304 pts/0    S+   11:28   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox slack
```

Answer (score 9):

The newer slacks explicitly disable WebRTCPipeWireCapturer, but you can get around that by editing the JS resource file directly. There's some integrity checking, and it needed to be the same length or Slack wouldn't start at all, but the following command worked for me on `4.35.121`. Of course need to pass in the command line option `--enable-features=WebRTCPipeWireCapturer` as before and/or put it in a desktop file.

```
sudo sed -i'.backup' -e 's/,"WebRTCPipeWireCapturer"/,"LebRTCPipeWireCapturer"/' /usr/lib/slack/resources/app.asar
```

The desktop file can be in `~/.local/share/applications/slack.desktop` and won't be clobbered by updates, but the app.asar patching needs to be repeated after each update.

Comment: thanks a lot for this investigation and the post.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [thread](https://forums.slackcommunity.com/s/question/0D53a00009BSEGACA5/when-will-slack-support-wayland-screen-sharing-does-anyone-have-workarounds-or-hacks-to-make-it-work?language=en_US) latest Wyaland working version was slack-desktop-4.29.149

One can download it , install and run with workinig screen sharing using followin commands

```
#Download
wget https://downloads.slack-edge.com/releases/linux/4.29.149/prod/x64/slack-desktop-4.29.149-amd64.deb
#install
sudo dpkg -i slack-desktop-4.29.149-amd64.deb 
#run and check whether screen sharing works
slack --enable-features=WebRTCPipeWireCapturer
```

edit .desktop file if its working

```
nano /usr/share/applications/slack.desktop
```